# Como uma recompilação dinâmica deveria funcionar?

Tags: c++, emulador

As vezes lendo sobre emulação e até mesmo desenvolvendo meus próprios emuladores é inevitável não se deparar com o assunto.

Basicamente existe dois tipos de emulação, a por meio de interpretação ou recompilação dinâmica,a interpretação basicamente interpreta a operação e executa.
Mas e a recompilação? Basicamente eu penso que deveria ser algo como transformar o código do jogo em um código para a plataforma nativa. Ai é que esta, existem diversos emuladores que executam em diversos tipos de processadores, Então como o emulador ira transformar aquilo em algo nativo? Ex: (Imagino algo executando em um android, o android tem toda uma SDK e diversos tipos de arquiteturas de processadores (arm, etc).

Então como um emulador recompila a rom?